# How to set up formula in repeated measures ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

I have a dependent Variable (`Reaction.Time`) which is measured in a control group and a experimental group (`Variable Group`).
I want to know which effect the group has on the reaction time.
The setup is the following:
I have about 20 individuals (`ID`) in the control and the experimental group. For each one the reaction time is measured in 3 different conditions/difficulties (`Condition`) and at 5 different time points (`Session`). I also want to add a covariate `Accuracy` to my model. 
Now I have no idea if my code is correct and how to interpret the results:

```
summary(aov(Reaction.Time ~ Group*(Session+Condition) + Accuracy + Error(factor(ID)/(Session*Condition)), 
           data = Data))
```

This is the result:

```
Error: factor(ID)
              Df   Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
Group          1   104874  104874   0.316  0.577
Accuracy  1       31      31   0.000  0.992
Residuals     41 13613839  332045               

Error: factor(ID):Session
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Session         4  366712   91678   8.931 1.47e-06 ***
Accuracy   1  235553  235553  22.946 3.66e-06 ***
Group:Session   4   34940    8735   0.851    0.495    
Residuals     167 1714316   10265                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: factor(ID):Condition
                Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Condition        2 6798723 3399361  82.040 <2e-16 ***
Accuracy    1   56156   56156   1.355  0.248    
Group:Condition  2   67846   33923   0.819  0.445    
Residuals       83 3439120   41435                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Error: factor(ID):Session:Condition
               Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
Accuracy   1  143467  143467   23.84 1.59e-06 ***
Residuals     351 2111956    6017
```

I do not know why there are some coefficients in different "groups" like "`Error: factor(ID):Session:Condition`" and what these groups mean.

Comment: you specified factor(ID)/(Session*Condition) as error term, so it will calculate the errors of ID nested within interaction of Session and Condition. But which variable are you interested in?

Comment: I am interested in if the variable group has an effect on the reaction time. I also want to know if there is an interaction in condition and group and in session and group

Comment: Ok I see, so in general, across most samples, Group does not have an effect (Group, p=0.577). You don't see a specific effect of Group in either Condition or Session (look under Group:Condition or Group:Session)

Comment: Yes, I already saw it clearly in plots that group will not have an effect. What do these categories mean like Error: factor(ID):Condition? And why are the coefficients for Accuracy different in these groups? I really do not know how to interpret the model at all.

Comment: Hi @Tobi, sorry I had to check aov again, so it goes like this, with repeated measure anova, you want to separate the variance into between group (what you are interested in) and within group( nuisance or blocking variables such as Group and Session) in your case.

Comment: In your summary results, they show that when you consider the within groups variance at different levels, e.g consider only factor(ID) and so it gets more and more complex. These are the between groups variance explained, not coefficients, so Accuracy is estimated many times depending on what you define as within group variance

Comment: Maybe try something easier, like aov(Reaction.Time ~ Group*(Session+Condition) + Accuracy + Error(factor(ID)+Session+Condition)), 
           data = Data)